# Using a php variable inside Jquery, as a dinamically created background image

Tags: php, jquery

I've already seen some similar posts but I think my case is different.
I have the following code:

```
$(".imagem .bottom-buttons").on("click", ".ver-emb", function(event){
        var Image = <?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>;
//row-embalagem comes from a query search to the database.
        $(".slider-img").css("background-image", "url(../assets/imagens/<?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>)");
        $(this).addClass( "ver-prod" );
        $(this).removeClass( "ver-emb" );
        $(this).text( "Ver Produto" );
    });
```

I've read that you need to put the php variable into jquery variable, but how do I apply that new Jquery variable to the background-image url ?

Comment: you missed quotes, `var Image = '<?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>';`  this may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use it the same way you use any variable in JavaScript:

```
"url(../assets/imagens/" + Image + ")"
```

Additionally, if your variable is a string (you're using it as a string) then strings need to be surrounded by quotes:

```
var Image = "<?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot that I could append that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".imagem .bottom-buttons").on("click", ".ver-emb", function(event){
            var Image = '<?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>';
    //row-embalagem comes from a query search to the database.
            $(".slider-img").css("background-image", "url(../assets/imagens/"+image+")");
            $(this).addClass( "ver-prod" );
            $(this).removeClass( "ver-emb" );
            $(this).text( "Ver Produto" );
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append the Image var in the url, like this:

```
$(".imagem .bottom-buttons").on("click", ".ver-emb", function(event){
    var Image = "<?php echo $row->embalagem; ?>";
    $(".slider-img").css("background-image", "url(../assets/imagens/"+Image+")");
    $(this).addClass( "ver-prod" )
    $(this).removeClass( "ver-emb" );
    $(this).text( "Ver Produto" );
});
```